# What's a fix for a cabinet door that fits to the frame otherwise except for one corner?

Tags: doors

What's a fix for a cabinet door that fits to the frame otherwise except for one corner?

[image]

The adjustments are already fully towards the frame so that using these it's not possible to put the door nearer the frame. So are the hinges too "out" from the frame? Something else? All the other corners seem to fit okay except for this bottom-left corner.

I don't quite understand how the "smaller gap" can seem like a perfect fit, but the opposite gum-corner then does not. And given that the top of the door fits perfectly, then I don't understand how the bottom-right corner could be misaligned.

The corner can be pushed to fit. But it "jumps" back to the gap.

[image]

Comment: Please post a photo of the hinge

Comment: I think you are speaking of a cabinet door, and it is slightly warped.

Comment: @RMDman Not sure how to determine that. But yes based on that if the top fits perfectly and one of the bottom corners does then so should the fourth corner.

Comment: ATM, I think of just trying to move the bottom hinge more inward.

Comment: Do you have a metal ruler, @mavavilj? If so, place it on edge on the door, diagonally from one corner to the other. Are there any gaps between the ruler and door (excluding decorative gaps in the door)? Check the other diagonal. Check each side of the door, top to bottom, and the top/bottom side-to-side. If you find any gaps, the door is warped. Depending on _how_ warped, you may not be able to adjust the hinges to account for the warp and your best bet may be to replace the door.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes actually, it sort of seems as if the opposite corner (bottom-right) has small curvature towards the inside. Which would explain why that corner fits perfectly, while the bottom-left corner is left in air. Not sure how it got that way.

Comment: It's wood. Wood (even particle board/MDF/plywood) moves over time. It's one of the joys of a natural product...

Comment: You might try adjusting the top right corner hinge outward a tiny bit to pivot the warped area inward. You’ll effectively be splitting the difference in the hope that neither top nor bottom are as noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that your cabinet door is warped (per this comment on the OP):

> Yes actually, it sort of seems as if the opposite corner (bottom-right) has small curvature towards the inside. Which would explain why that corner fits perfectly, while the bottom-left corner is left in air.

It's entirely possible that this warpage exceeds the hinges' adjustment range and, therefore, it may be impossible to get this door to close all the way around.

I see four possible solutions:

1. Replace the door with a new, flat one.

   - You may be able to get a replacement from the manufacturer, if they still make this door style.
   - You might be able to hire a local woodworker/cabinet shop to create a copy/
2. Attempt to flatten the door.

   - This may or may not work well, depending upon what it's made of, among other factors.
   - Again, a local woodworker or cabinet shop may be able to help you out.
   - The [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com) sister site has a lot of questions & answers about straightening wood products, so you can check there to see what's involved.
3. Replace the hinges with new ones with more adjustment range.

   - This may or may not work. Depending on how much warp, it may just be out of range of any commonly available, reasonably priced hinge.
   - Check local or online woodworking stores (Rockler and Woodcrafters, for example, are two big-name chains in the US, usually staffed by knowledgeable woodworkers who enjoy what they do, local lumber yards may also be able to help you out) for a good selection of hinges and people who are most likely to be able to help you. (Big box stores will have a limited selection and their people may not be as knowledgeable.)
4. Live with it as is.

   - This is the classic, and in many cases, default, option.

Comment: Since the gap is small. I thought of also pushing it every day so that It might eventually warp from the other corner too.

Comment: You don't have enough days to make that happen. As noted in the answer, go check out [woodworking.se] to see what it takes to straighten a warped board/panel/door. Water, steam, pressure, clamping. It takes a _lot_ of effort and there's no guarantee you'll get back to flat and that it won't warp again in the future.